# Fetching Related Records from flow Data Table

Tags: visual-workflow, datatable, screen-flow

I'm trying to display a chosen value from a data table's lookup field, but it's coming up as null. I've checked the permissions, and this is related to the User lookup field, where I'm trying to get the name and other info.

According to the documentation, it seems like I can’t display the lookup field name of selected record from data table. But what do they mean by "object formula fields"? I tried referencing the selected value of a data table record in a formula field, and it didn't work either. Any ideas?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "object formula fields" Salesforce refers to [custom fields that are formulas](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_formulas.htm&type=5). E.g. you could create a field "Account Name" (AccountName__c) on Contact, which points at the name of the Contacts' Account. You can then refer to AccountName__c in your Flow Data Table displaying Contact records.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out already!